# Make PHP show the info of the database row depending on ID

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm building a movie database to learn PHP. It's almost complete but i don't know how to make the update form do what i want it to do!

So basically what i want to do is when the user clicks "edit" on one of the movies they are sent to a new page where they can edit the info. This all works.

Problem is that only ONE of the database rows show, no matter what movie you click "edit" on!

I would like to be able to direct the user to the correct form that they want to edit.

I did try putting my update form in a foreach loop, that worked but it printed the form for each movie. I just want one form depending on what movie "edit" has been clicked on index.php

So is what i want to do possible in PHP? I have been googling since two days ago but the only thing i have managed to make work is the foreach loop around my update form.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once "login.php";
$bibliotek = array();

    if(isset($_POST["title"])) {

    if($_POST['title'] || $_POST['director']) {
    // Skicka form data till databas
    $stmt = $db -> prepare("UPDATE `filmer` 
                   SET `id`=?,
                   `title`=?,
                   `director`=?,
                   `year`=?,
                   `category_id`=? 
                   WHERE 1");
    $stmt -> bind_param('issii', $_POST['id'] , $_POST['title'], $_POST['director'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['category_id']);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
    // Förhindra form-spam
    header('location:index.php');
    }
}


if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM filmer
                         JOIN kategorier ON filmer.category_id = kategorier.category_id")) {
    if($results->num_rows) {
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $bibliotek[] = $row;
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}
?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Uppdatera</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php 
foreach($bibliotek as $b) {
    $info = $b;
}
?> 
    <form action='update.php' method='post'>

            <p><input type="radio" id="action" name="category_id" value="1">
            <label for="action">Action</label></p>

            <p><input type="radio" id="deckare" name="category_id" value="2">
            <label for="deckare">Deckare</label></p>

            <p><input type="radio" id="drama" name="category_id" value="3">
            <label for="drama">Drama</label></p>

            <p><input type="radio" id="fantasy" name="category_id" value="4">
            <label for="fantasy">Fantasy</label></p>

            <p><input type="radio" id="sci-fi" name="category_id" value="5">
            <label for="sci-fi">Science Fiction</label></p>



            <p><label for="title">Titel: </label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $b->title; ?>"></p>

            <p><label for="director">Regissör: </label>
            <input type="text" id="director" name="director" value="<?php echo $b->director; ?>"></p>

            <p><label for="year">År: </label>
            <input type="text" id="year" name="year" value="<?php echo $b->year; ?>"></p>

            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $b->id; ?>" name="id">

            <input type="submit" value="Lagra"> <a href="index.php">Tillbaka</a>

    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be honest, this is the sort of thing that you'd find in an introductory PHP/MySQL tutorial.  At a high level, your "list" page would create links to your "edit" page, one on each row of data, and each link would include an identifier for that row.  (The value of an `id` field for example.)  The "edit" page would receive that value from the query string and use it in a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement.  It's also really not clear what you're doing with that `UPDATE` statement.  `WHERE 1` sounds like it's going to update *every row* (or no row)...

Comment: Each edit button must have a movie ID linked with it so you can determine which edit button was clicked

Comment: the MySQL isn't finished yet and yes i am a beginner. I watched a ton of tutorials but none of them showed how to connect two PHP pages with the id from the database.

Comment: I'll try that Neyte, thanks guys for your quick replies!! Hopefully i can get done today!! :D

Comment: would be easier to predefine `$id=$_POST['id'];` then doing  `WHERE id='$id'");` instead of `WHERE 1");` type of thing. But you would probably need to remove `SET id=?,` since I doubt you want to update the id row. Or `WHERE id=?` and keep the bind.